# trigger jquery form submit script

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a validation script that runs when a user clicks the form submit button.

I want to pass variables to this form and auto execute the validation script by injecting a piece of code.

I have tried this:

```
 $('#theform').submit();
```

but it bypasses the validation that would have happened had a user manually clicked the button.

is there a way to emulate a user 'click' and execute the form submit triggers.

Comment: can you provide the rest of your script

Comment: i want to trigger this...   $('#theform').submit( function() { });

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#theform").submit(function() {
    // If the validation function returns true, then submit
    if(my_validation_function())
        return true;
    // If the validation function returns flase, don't submit
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed, by placing inside this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.  
 });
```